# Creating dynamic select forms based on selection

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a small project.

- The initial select form has N options.
- Making a selection will pop up another select form based on what it is.
  Example: Choose a pet: dog, cat (Chooses dog), displays types of dogs.

I am doing this using JSON and JS but im not sure I have the correct understanding of how things should be working.

What my thought process is for this, when a selection is made.. send that string to a method and then search the JSON object for that string, pull that data and create the new select.

However, it doesnt appear to be working and I think my lack of knowledge with both is hindering my progress here.

JSON

```js
var obj = {  
   "option":[  
      {  
         "text":"Choose Team",
         "value":"choose"
      },
      {  
         "text":"Eagles",
         "value":"d"
      },
      {  
         "text":"Falcons",
         "value":"c"
      },
      {  
         "text":"Browns",
         "value":"b"
      }
   ],
   "Eagles":[  
      {  
         "text":"Choose Player",
         "value":"Choose"
      },
      {  
         "text":"Eagles",
         "value":"d"
      },
      {  
         "text":"Falcons",
         "value":"c"
      },
      {  
         "text":"Browns",
         "value":"b"
      }
   ]
};
```

And then the JS function that creates a new select box based on the selection string

```
function changeSelect(select){
    var test = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.test.length; i++){
        var objOption = document.createElement( 'option' );
        objOption.setAttribute( 'value', obj.test[i].value);
        objOption.appendChild( document.createTextNode( obj.test[i].text) );
    }                   
}
```

Is there a reason `obj.Eagles[i].text` will create my new select form with the correct values but `obj.test[i].text` doesn't work? (Text is a variable with the String "Eagles" assigned to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...  I had to change the data slightly.

```js
(function(select1, select2) {
    select1 = document.getElementById(select1);
    select2 = document.getElementById(select2);
    var obj = {
        "option": [{
            "text": "Choose Team",
            "value": "choose"
        }, {
            "text": "Eagles",
            "value": "Eagles"
        }, {
            "text": "Falcons",
            "value": "Falcons"
        }, {
            "text": "Browns",
            "value": "Browns"
        }],
        "Eagles": [{
            "text": "Choose Player",
            "value": "Choose"
        }, {
            "text": "Agholor, Nelson",
            "value": "d"
        }, {
            "text": "Ajirotutu, Seyi",
            "value": "c"
        }, {
            "text": "Bradford, Sam",
            "value": "b"
        }]
    };

    function populateSelect(select, data) {
        for (var i = 0, objOption, element; element = data[i++];) {
            objOption = document.createElement('option');
            objOption.value = element.value;
            objOption.innerHTML = element.text;
            select.appendChild(objOption);
        }
    }

    function changeSelect2(event) {
        var test = event.target.value,
            innerArray = obj[test];
        select2.options.length = 0;
        if (innerArray) {
            populateSelect(select2, innerArray);
        }
    }

    populateSelect(select1, obj.option);
    select1.addEventListener("change", changeSelect2, false);
})("select1", "select2");
```

```html
<select id="select1"></select>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

Comment: Cant thank you enough, this points me in the right direction!